# Sending song metadata to a v2.6 Shoutcast server using CURL in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, curl, shoutcast

I am attempting to send song metadata to a v2.6 Shoutcast server. Obviously, I can’t share the username and passwords here, but if I enter the following format in a web browser, it works:

```
http://<serverusername>:<serverpassword>@<IPaddress>:<port>/admin.cgi?<streampassword>&mode=updinfo&song=XXXXXXX – XXXXXXX
```

However, I want to send updated metadata using a Windows Batch file. I have used CURL successfully before to send HTTP commands but I don’t appear to be able to get it to work in this instance. I have tried various CURL configurations such as:

```
CURL http://<serverusername>:<serverpassword>@<IPaddress>:<port>/admin.cgi -d <streampassword>&mode=updinfo&song=XXXXXXX – XXXXXXX
```

It does appear to be connecting to the server since it returns quite a bit of log information, but no errors. If I change the username or password, then it fails authentication.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You forgot to put double-quotes around the url and POST-string. And in Batch you mostly likely have to escape the ampersands!

Comment: @Reino Thank you very much. Adding the double quotes fixed the issue and I didn't need to escape the ampersands. All working